# Use variable outside of map function with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I'm having a little problem with some vars.

My code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
var sch = require('../models/schema');

export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  render() {

    sch.find(function(err,models){
       //???
    });

    return (
      <div className="home">
        Afiez ceva {models}
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

How to achieve this? I ve tried all the posibilites.
I want to be able to render someting like {models} or {models[0].whatever} ..
Some tip please?

Reference for sch:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

var schValue = new mongoose.Schema({
  asd: String
});

schValue.set( 'collection', 'ecommerce' );

module.exports = mongoose.model('sch', schValue);
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need to use callbacks or promises.

Comment: Should i use redux ?

Comment: You don't have to use redux. Although it is good to scale up you application. I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you need to use the `state`. You should make a function that uses `setState()` and use `this.state` inside your render function. Once the `state` updates, your component will rerender automatically : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Or maybe not. if you just want to render a list,  you have to `map` over this list. and return this `map` inside the render function.

Comment: not sure how to do this

Comment: I ll try an answer. One minute

Comment: Are you on the back-end or the front-end ? Are you using react-isomorphic?

Comment: On the backend you fetch the data before rendering the component. In this case redux helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it but is that something like this you need :

```
  export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      models: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    sch.find({}, (err, models) => {
      this.setState({ models });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        {this.state.models.map(model => {
          return model;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: getModels not defined

Comment: Sorry again. I reedited. it should be this.getModels()

Comment: TypeError: sch.map is not a function

Comment: `map` works on array. Could you add to your question, what is `sch` ?

Comment: I am sorry. I misunderstood your question. I dont think my answer apply to your question

Comment: Well, I ll give it a last try...let me know if it works